# user with Readers access can't access a site or read a list; What else could be wrong?

Tags: permissions, access-denied

Reader has read site, read list etc. But still a user can't visit a site or read lists. Any ideas guys?

user with Readers access can't access a site or read a list; What else could be wrong?

Comment: theres not much meat to go on here. You should update your question with as much info as possible to get good answers -some of this info is already present in comments below

Answer (score 1):

I'd check lists and libraries such as the Style Library or SiteAssets, make sure they have access, as the site's pages may have artefacts that point there.

Comment: James: I checked both of those libs and they have all authenticated users with read access. Actually other users with "Reader Access" can access the site and list in question. It just one particular user.

Comment: Ah, just one? Do they have a particular entry in the Users list in the site collection? Or just a member of an active directory security group?

Comment: that particular user is added to the site collections' web. i hv also added her to a sharepoint group.

Comment: Absolutely certain she doesn't exist in a group that might have access explicitly revoked?

Comment: When I did a Check Permissions for the user I see like below.<ul>
Site Readers Given directly
Site Readers Given through the "style resource readers" group.
Site Readers Given through the "domain\somegroup" group.
Site Readers Given through the "Sales" group. 
Site Readers Given through the "Sales Site visitors" group.</ul>